# react-native-socketio getting error in SocketIO connection just in iOS

Tags: react-native, socket.io, react-native-ios

> this.socket = new SocketIO('http://myserver.com:3000/', {secure: true}); //<-- error here
>   this.socket.on('connect', () => { this.socket.emit('authentication', { token: this.state.valid, id_user: this.state.id });

`undefined is not an object (evaluating this.sockets.initialize)`

react-native: 0.42
**macOs**

Observation :In Android works well